# How to set proxy server in Linux Container in Docker for Windows

Tags: docker

I am new to Docker and just started my first steps with Docker for Windows on Windows 10. I installed the newest version of Docker.

I am running my system in a corporate environment behind a common security layer. For outbound connections we have to use a proxy. I have configured HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY in windows, and If I configure Docker to use “Windows containers” everything works like a charm. If I switch to “Linux Containers” then the proxy connection is not detected by Docker and it fails to pull any image from internet.

A simple docker run hello-world quits with following error message: “Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).”

Obviously the Linux Container mode seems to do things differently from the Windows mode. I would like to understand how I should configure the Linux container to detect the proxy server?

Comment: Maybe you have already done it but have you set up proxy for docker itself? Right click on docker icon in taskbar-> Settings -> Proxy(Or network).

Comment: It worked. Can you put this comment as answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that you have also provided proxy settings for docker daemon itself.

To do this:

- Right click on docker icon in the taskbar
- Click Settings
- On Proxies section provide your proxy setup.

Note that docker will restart to load the new configuration.